# ASP.NET Membership Provider failing on different SQL instance

Tags: asp.net, sql, membership-provider

I am using the ASP.NET Membership Schema using aspnet_regsql.exe on SQL1 (hosted via windows server), I had a backup of that sql database restored on SQL2 (local instance).

However, when I have my connection string pointed to SQL2, authentication is failing @

```
Membership.ValidateUser
```

It is returning a false, but when I change my connection string back to SQL1, it returns true, this is happening on same codebase. I am not sure what is causing this, I have tried the following

- Checked SQL1 and SQL2 passwords and salts, they match exactly
- Tried using SQL Compare to see if there was something different, the schema
  matches exactly
- Checked SQL login permissions, they both match

Any ideas?

Comment: salt is created from a hash with the machine key (which is in web.config so could be a red herring if this is the same web server)? nothing stopping you running a sql trace to get the commands and try running those in QA. Also, "failing" means it returns false?

Comment: yeah, i mean "failing" as in ValidateUsers returns false, web.config doesn't have machine key set, but i'll check a sql trace to see whats different, assumed it just uses the stored salt and nothing else machine related, so what you are saying is that the stored location can not be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encrypted password is created from a hash of the machine key (which is in web.config so could be a red herring if this is the same web server?) + actual pwd + randomly generated password salt.

Try running a sql trace to capture the issued commands and try running those in QA. This would show up a hash mismatch or simple auth fail.

Maybe you should force the machine key, look for machine.config and copy it from there into your local web.config.

My past pain-history says if ur still scratching your head - go find a decent decompiler (ILSpy) and attach your debugger to the dll and step through as you would if it were your own code.

[Machine key in Forms-Auth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm a little confused about machine key though, this happened on same machine (worked when pointing to SQL1 on local box), unless its a machine key related to SQL?

Comment: yeah true its a stab in the dark - forms-auth is a bit like the dark arts / black magic. the machine key is only used by the web server tapping into the asp.net membership api. so unless you know the original machine key (none says its the one in machine.config), it's something else.

Comment: WOW, I think i see what the problem was, when I did a trace, it was executing the GetPasswordWithFormat, when I ran it manually, it error out due to clr not enabled, which might be enabled on our servers.. doh!   Accepting answer since you got me to that solution

Answer (score 1):

If password is stored as **hashed**, it doesn't use machine key.

However, password is stored as **encrypted**, it uses machine key.

If they are mixed and machine key is not explicitly set in web.config, only thing you can do is to retrieve the machine key from old server using this method -

[How to read Auto Generated machine key?](http://aspnetresources.com/blog/how_to_read_auto_generated_machinekey)

Rule of thumb is you want to include machine key in web.config. *We learn the hard way that Azure creates machine key automatically if you do not set one in web.config.*